# Do you have to patch the security provider when the device runs Android M?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, boringssl

Android M came packed with the new security provider: BoringSSL. Therefore I wonder: do I still have to update the SecurityProvider on Android M devices using the Dynamic Security Provider from Google Play Services (e.g.: `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getContext());`) ?

Comment: Interesting question... [Updating Your Security Provider to Protect Against SSL Exploits](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html) names OpenSSL but not BoringSSL. Err on the side of caution and update BoringSSL until AOSP clearly states otherwise. Your users will thank you, and you will avoid the loss of reputation (if those things matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is, for now: allways patch it! Because, basically: you don't know whether any of the-by-the-manufacturer-provided Security providers within Android are patched correctly! So I am patching always.